# Load More from Google API RSS Feed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rss, ionic-framework, rss-reader

I'm building an RSS Feed Reader using this tutorial here: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/create-an-rss-reader-using-angularjs-and-ionicframework/

Using the Google feed API is there any way to load more results from the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parameter

> num  The number of entries to return. Default is 4 and maximum is 100

Something like this

```
$http.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load", { params: { "v": "1.0", "q": "http://blog.nraboy.com/feed/", "num": "100" } })
```

How many entries does the source publish? The feed API can't display more than there are available.